# Can anyone explain me about shared memory in an OS

Tags: operating-systems, dll, shared-libraries

Can anyone explain me how is shared memory related to the operating system?

Recently I am seeing it mentioned frequently.

What does it exactly mean ? It is a part of memory in RAM ?

Comment: "Shared memory" can mean different things, depending on the context. Please be more specific about the context in which you have seen this mentioned, so we can answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

This means that several programs can use the same DLL without having it loaded several time in the RAM (this would causes a very high memory usage if you have the shell32.dll loaded 50 times).

MS explained it here in this video:

**Defrag Tools: #7 - VMMap**

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-7-VMMap#time=03m35s

Answer (score 1):

There are different techniques to share memory with different outcomes:

1. There's a program level shared memory (like IPC or dbus) for inter-process communication. Many different programs can use it to communicate and share data.
2. There's a system level shared memory, where system linker can hold libraries that were used by more than one process.
3. There's a hardware level shared memory, when a number of CPUs have access to a one big chunk of RAM.

For a more precise explanation you can hit a [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory).